# What MIME type should I use for jQuery Autocomplete queries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, mime-types

The [jQuery Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) plugin relies on an odd response format. Specifically, it's a newline-separated list of pipe-delimited pairs, the first entry of each pair being some formatted text, the latter being a JSON object with some data.

An example:

```
Fuzzy Bunnies|{ id: '1234-fuzzy-bunnies', type: 'slippers' }
Loud Hawaiian Shirt|{ id: '3993-loud-hawaiian-shirt', type: 'shirt', sizes: ['S', 'M', 'L'] }
```

My question is: what sort of MIME type makes sense for this? It's not exactly `application/json` because of that odd pipe and the fact that the list is newline-delimited, not expresses as a Javascript array. Nor is it `text/plain` since only the first part is plain text (and even that might allow markup -- I'm not sure).

Comment: Why don’t you use Json for the whole data?

Comment: Because _I_ don't get to pick what format the plugin accepts. I'd have to rewrite the plugin to get it to parse JSON.

Answer (score 4):

You should send it as `text/plain`, because that is what it really is. The fact that some part of that text has a specific meaning, doesn't mean that the file is `json`.

Otherwise, for example, you could argue that a binary file storing a single text variable is a text file.

If you send that file as `json` you could have some problems, as is not a valid `json` file.

Comment: +1. You could also send it (or anything) as application/octet-stream to be completely non-specific about what type it is. However, browsers will always attempt to decode the bytes into a Unicode string in resposneText (defaulting to using UTF-8).

Answer (score -1):

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=iso-8859-1
```